# Pythonnet: cannot access to dll class

Tags: python.net

I'm having issues trying to load a Dll's class made in c# with pythonnet

Here's the dll project config (VS)

[image]

Here's the class code

```
using System;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1{   
        public void test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from a library");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the dll info

[image]

And the script

```py
import clr
clr.AddReference('ClassLibraryAss')
from ClassLibraryAss import Class1
x = Class1()
x.test()
```

Is able to find the assembly. I follow some examples and it can't be more difficult than this.

This is the output

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\testDLL.py", line 23, in <module>
    from ClassLibraryAss import Class1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ClassLibraryAss'
```

I tried different ways to load the module but with no luck

#### Environment

- Pythonnet version: 2.5.2 (Also tried 2.5.1)
- Python version: 3.8.0
- Operating System: Windows 10
- Visual studio 2019 (I didn't tried other)

Answer (score 0):

In your `from XXX import Class1` `XXX` should be the namespace where `Class1` resides, not the DLL name

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the dll was made in .net core and pythonnet by default don't work with that.

[Acording to the issue](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/984)

So making the dll with .net framework works. In the issue says a way to make this run with net core dlls, I didn't try it though

```py
import clr
#I made a dll with .net Framework 4.8 called ClassLibraryNetF 
from ClassLibraryNetF import Class1

x = Class1()
x.test()
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling on this question while debuggin similar problem, pythonnet wouldn't load the assembly correctly if your script is being ran as a module, e.g. `python -m Package.Module`
and inside you've added assembly folder to `sys.path`

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Assemblies"))
clr.AddReference("MyAssembly")

import MyAssembly
from MyAssembly import SimpleClass
```

Don't know why, but the latest version reproduces this on Win 10, python 3.9.
Probably something to do with the way pythonnet works with modules.

if you run it as a script from it's folder (`python Module.py`), it works fine.